# Configuring SSL certificate to SINGLE Elastic Beanstalk TOMCAT instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im trying to install SSL certificates in my TOMCAT elastic beanstalk EC2 instance. I also want my application listening to HTTPS requests on port 443. As start point I based my solution on [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html).

After a while making a lot of tries I could not install my certificate or make port 443 listen to HTTPS requests.

Those are the steps I followed:

1) I build a WAR with a .ebextensions folder at src ROOT,as below

```
 ROOT.war
      |
       WEB-INF
       META-INF
       .ebextensions
           |
            https-instance-single.config
            https-instance.config
```

2) **https-instance.config** file content

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod_ssl : []

container_commands:
  1killhttpd:
    command: "killall httpd"
    ignoreErrors: true
  2wait:
    command: "sleep 3"

files:
  # Apache HTTPS configuration
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        SSLEngine             on
        SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        SSLCipherSuite           EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder   On

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPreserveHost on
      </VirtualHost>


  # Public certificate
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

3) **https-instance-single.config** file content

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

4) Then I deployed my WAR using elastic beanstalk console (none error message was thrown during the process, at least at console).

After Deployed My war as specified, my web application was running perfectly, but with no SSL configurations and HTTPS requests was not being redirected to port 443. Worse, the application was not even listening to HTTPS requests.

Anyone has a light?? I dont want to use ELB (Elastic load balancer) because Im migrating a bunch of small applications and that would bring me a considerable increase of costs (about 20 dollars per app).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is all steps I followed to solve my problem:

1) I removed /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file declaration block from  https-instance.config

2) I added the file itself at .ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf. Bellow the file content:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ServerName [YOUR APP ENDPOINT HERE i.e www.mydomain.com]
  SSLEngine             on
  SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
  SSLCipherSuite           EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
  SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder   On

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
  Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

**Important:** Dont forget to add a line with your **server name**

3) This step is optional, just do it If you want to redirect all your http requests from port 80 to 443 you must add a config file with port 80 listener configuration. I named it elasticbeanstalk.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ServerName [YOUR APP ENDPOINT HERE i.e www.mydomain.com]
  Redirect permanent / https://[YOUR APP ENDPOINT HERE i.e www.mydomain.com]/

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

Finnaly, thats how my war has its directories organized:

```
ROOT.war
      |
       WEB-INF
       META-INF
       .ebextensions
           |
            https-instance-single.config
            https-instance.config
           |
            httpd
                 |
                  conf.d
                        |
                         elasticbeanstalk.conf
                         ssl.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I discovered the answer in the [Java Tomcat Platform](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html#java-tomcat-proxy-apache) documentation for Elastic Beanstalk.  Instead of creating the ssl.conf file through the configuration in the http-instance.config file, you need to create the file yourself in .ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.